# Insert/delete on unordered_map with multiple threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety

I have use-case where multiple threads will be adding/deleting different keys in `unordered_map` concurrently? Every thread will be reading/writing exactly same keys and this key will be different for each thread.

from http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container#Thread_safety, there is this point: "Different elements in the same container can be modified concurrently by different threads", does it mean only updating existing key,value pair? Does it also support insert/delete with different keys?

Comment: No insert/delete. Just like you can operate on individual, distinct, elements in a vector with multiple threads but not insert or delete elements.

Comment: @doug how about read x key and insert y key?

Comment: Nope. Changing, adding, deleting key is very thread unsafe because it affects other entry locations.